# What does linear layout refer to in Kamadao_kawai layout in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I am drawing a graph using Kamado Kawai layout in Networkx

In the docs, it says

pos (dict or None optional (default=None)) – Initial positions for nodes as a dictionary with node as keys and values as a coordinate list or tuple. If None, then use circular_layout() for dim >= 2 and a linear layout for dim == 1.

I know what circular_layout method is but I can't find any explanation on linear layout.

What is it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to get the `pos` with the dimension set to `2`, you will get the following:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(5)
pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G, dim=1)
print(pos)
# {0: array([-1.]),
#  1: array([-0.4999998]),
#  2: array([-2.92838698e-07]),
#  3: array([0.50000022]),
#  4: array([0.99999987])}
```

The positions are returned for a 1-D plane(this is the `linear layout` that is referred in the docs). In a 1-D plane you only need 1 point as a co-ordinate to plot, hence the second pair of co-ordinates is missing. You can also see house these 1-D points are generated [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/b87b33f6ffdda605d8809680c1ebe22d8fba33f1/networkx/drawing/layout.py#L721).

Wheareas, if the `dim=2`, you will get

import networkx as nx

```
G = nx.path_graph(5)
pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G, dim=1)
print(pos)
# {0: array([0.72171323, 1.        ]),
# 1: array([0.36392114, 0.49778359]),
# 2: array([ 0.00271944, -0.00197535]),
# 3: array([-0.35988085, -0.50072794]),
# 4: array([-0.72847295, -0.99508031])}
```

Now, the points are returned for a 2-D plane, i.e. you have both `x` and `y` co-ordinates.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But when I try to draw graph using ```networkx.draw(g, pos=networkx.kamada_kawai_layout(g, dim=1))```, I get IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with axis 1. How can I draw it?